# Redirecting PathUrl to PathUrl

Tags: javascript, html, dns

How should I add a redirect if in the URL domain pathurl detects: /pl/

to the path: ?wmc-currency=PLN

I tried to do it via JavaScipt, but it only works on the browser: Chrome and Opera

It does not work, for example, on the phone in safari, in the browser: Edge

Code:

> if(window.location.pathname.toString().includes(
> "/pl/")) {
>  if(window.location.search.toString().includes("?wmc-currency")) {
>
>  Stop
>  }
>  else{
>  window.location.assign("?wmc-currency=PLN");
>  }
>  }

How should I add a redirect if in the URL domain pathurl detects: /pl/

to the path: ?wmc-currency=PLN

Woocommerce store